# Local installation of Prestashop redirects to localhost instead of subfolder

Tags: php, .htaccess, prestashop

I was hired to maintain a website running on Prestashop 1.6. The problem is, the admin is working fine, but I can't access any page on the site but the homepage.

Currently, the shop's URL in the database is : localhost

The physical_uri is : /folder/ that's where Prestashop's content is stored.

For example, when I navigate in localhost/folder/videos, I'm redirected to localhost/index.php, and I can't figure out why...

The previous developer created a set of RewriteRules in htaccess, here's one example :

```
RewriteRule ^videos/([-0-9a-zA-Z]+)-m([0-9]+)$ /index.php?controller=media&id=$2 [QSA,L]
```

After this set of rules is the rest of the file, generated by Prestashop.

I tried multiple solutions like setting a RewriteBase but nothing seems to work...

If anybody has an idea, It'll be nice !
Thx !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you do not plan to use your installation in subfolder on production, I guess for you be better (to avoid similar issues next time) use local domain,

e.g. by adding in hosts file `127.0.0.1 myshop.dev` and configure webserver virtual domain root to your "folder" folder, just move "folder" to one level with localhost root.

So you will can to work with `myshop.dev/video` without cnanges in rewrite rules as result.

Comment: Thanks, I tried that with MAMP Pro and indeed it worked. Adding /folder/ in the rewrite rule however did not worked... I still can't understand why, I got other Prestashop installed locally and every one works fine...

Comment: so, this rule works for you now or problem still exists?

Comment: The rule doesn't work, but the problem was solved by setting a virtual host with MAMP Pro.